# Inner-Join query is returning no data

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Trying to run a query which builds a list of reports that all have information stored about them. When i run this query without the INNER JOIN part it works fine, and there are a list of the reports with their information displayed respectively. When i try and run this with the INNER JOIN query inserted it returns no data. Both tables definitely have data in them, no idea what the issue could be. Thanks.

This is the query that works and returns data before the INNER JOIN method is added:

```
SELECT reports_tbl.photoname
    , reports_tbl.location
    , reports_tbl.details
    , reports_tbl.image
    , reports_tbl.spotteddate
    , reports_tbl.uploaddate
    , typesofphoto_tbl.typename 
FROM reports_tbl
```

This is the query that returns no data containing the INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT reports_tbl.photoname
     , reports_tbl.location
     , reports_tbl.details
     , reports_tbl.image
     , reports_tbl.spotteddate
     , reports_tbl.uploaddate
     , typesofphoto_tbl.typename 
FROM reports_tbl 
INNER JOIN typesofphoto_tbl 
ON reports_tbl.typeofphotoID = typesofphoto_tbl.ID
```

Comment: but do they have the corresponding id match?

Comment: You can try in query...to check if any common data are there

Comment: Something strange with data types of the joined column? Assuming that you have checked that there's at least one row in each table where that ID actually matches...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean James

Comment: What results do you get if you switch to an outer join?  Are there any rows that have data in all columns?

Answer (score 1):

> > INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH tables.
> >
> > LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched
> >     rows from the right table RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right
> >     table, and the matched rows from the left table 
> >     FULL JOIN: Return all rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

so, when you are using `Inner Join`, there is no match in both table `reports_tbl` and `typesofphoto_tbl` thats why you are not getting the data.

try `LEFT-JOIN`

```
SELECT reports_tbl.photoname
     , reports_tbl.location
     , reports_tbl.details
     , reports_tbl.image
     , reports_tbl.spotteddate
     , reports_tbl.uploaddate
     , typesofphoto_tbl.typename 
FROM reports_tbl 
LEFT JOIN typesofphoto_tbl 
ON reports_tbl.typeofphotoID = typesofphoto_tbl.ID
```

you'll get the record from the left table `reports_tbl` if there are no matching row in right table `typesofphoto_tbl` .